# How I can configure IBM Websphere application Server to send notification emails on out of sync?

Tags: ibm, websphere, application-server

I need to activate notification email on IBM WebSphere Network Deployment when the application servers are out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible since **every time** you make a change to your master configuration you need to synchronize with the node agent to apply it to the application servers. 
It is not a defect but a natural situation when you make changes to your (distributed) architecture.

In case you have problems with synchronization you can just set up Automatic synchronization or else examine your synchronization strategy.

The following should be useful:

- [Synchronization questions for WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21165847)
- [TroubleShooting: Synchronization problems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199305)

Comment: I worked on production environment and it is very critical environment and have financial impact , so I need to write bash script ( UNIX Environment to check my Application on both production server ) if out of sync inform me by email . so I need anything to get me the sync status between applications even though by using unix command line

Comment: If you insist you can write a wsadmin script to check synchronization status. More info here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21178926

Comment: I try the script in the link but I get an error : below is the output

Comment: wsadmin>set nodeSync [$AdminControl completeObjectNametype=NodeSync,node=$node,*]
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "set nodeSync [$AdminControl completeObjectNametype=NodeSync,node=$node,*]"; exception information:
 com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: error while eval'ing Jacl expression:
no accessible method "completeObjectNametype=NodeSync,node=tapps-a,*" in class com.ibm.ws.scripting.AdminControlClient
    while executing
"$AdminControl completeObjectNametype=NodeSync,node=$node,*"
    invoked from within
"set nodeSync [$AdminControl completeObjectNametype=NodeSync,node=$node,*]"